# Is it possible to implement parent class method using different name?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am inheriting from the tensorflow's `Model` class, in which I must implement the `call(self, inputs)` method.

```py
def call(self, inputs):
    encoded = self.encoder(inputs)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded
```

I wanted to implement it as a method `reconstruction(self, inputs)`.

Is there anyway to implement a parent class method and assigning it a new name?

Comment: In a word no. Did you mean: `def call(self, inputs): return self.reconstruction(inputs)`?

Comment: If you give your method a different name, it won't override the inherited method as expected.

Comment: Sure, you can implement anything under any name. But then it has nothing to do with the parent function, it’s just some other function. And probably nothing will call this other function with its different name, unless you do.

Comment: I want to implement call(self, inputs) as reconstruction(self, inputs). Implementation of the same method under different name. I thought that maybe there exist a decorator that would help me do it